# SQL Server database design with foreign keys

Tags: sql-server, database-design, foreign-key

See the following link for the (total) databse design:
https://sqldbm.com/Project/SQLServer/Share/_AUedvNutCEV2DGLJleUWA

I am not used to the database design first and then build it. But... for everything there is a first time... and I try to do make a database that is using standards and is using the power of SQL Server the correct way.

I am trying to create a database design where foreign keys are used.

The data for the tables `documentsets_metadata`, `documentset_casenumbers`, `documentset_costs`, `documentset_controls` & `link_id` cannot have data for `documentset_id` if there isnt a row with the same ID in `documentsets`.

The tables `routes`, `route_details`, `cotg` & `planetpress_controls` can have data without the `documentset_id` id being present in `documentsets`.

All the tables mentioned above (except for the `documentsets_metadata` table) have a 1:m relationship (Where `documentsets` is the parent table).

The tables below `documentsets` are the following:
`subsets`, `subdocuments`, `subdocuments` & `documents`.

the tables `subsets`, `subdocuments`, `documents` all have an m:m relationship so I thought the best way to create a database to get unique and correct that is to put a link table in between called `subdocuments_documents`.

Now I thought within this link table I only put foreign key references so that all the data in this table is always present in the subtables and when a row in `subset` is removed all the data in those subtables are also removed.

Do you guys think I am on the right track or I am totally going the wrong way?

Any help is appropriated!